# android how to receive notification if specific json value has been changed

Tags: android, json, push-notification, retrofit

Actually I have json url and I am developing app that read this json url.
I want to receive notification if the tr_id equals to my value and if the value of status changed to "Paid".
I have made a lot of search to do this but I am not got any solution.
I am tried to make broadcast receiver listen for internet connection and load the json url values and make notification if all conditions are ture.
but it is not working anymore and even toast message it not showed here is my try.

this is my NotificationReceiver class

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.apk4android.resturantapp.R;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;
    Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (isOnline(context)) {
        notificationListener();
    }

}


SharedPreferences sp;

private void notificationListener() {
    sp = context.getSharedPreferences("current_tr_id",         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    RegisterAPI2 registerAPI =         ApiClient.getApiClient2().create(RegisterAPI2.class);

    Call<TrResponse> req = registerAPI.getStatus();
    req.enqueue(new Callback<TrResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<TrResponse> call,     
retrofit2.Response<TrResponse> response) {

                        TrResponse post = response.body();

                        String tr_id = post.getTr_number().toString();
                        String status = post.getStatus().toString();
                        // make sure the tr_id of current order == tr_id of json
                        String currentID = sp.getString("currentID", "3");
                        Log.d("tr_id", "Current tr_id comes from user that paid the order = " + currentID);


                        if (status.equals("Paid") && !tr_id.equals("3") && tr_id.equals(currentID)) {
                            // make notification
                            notifyUser();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<TrResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        Log.d("TTTT CallBack", " Throwable is " + t + " Call  " + call.toString());

                    }

                }
    );

}

public boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
}

private void notifyUser() {
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContent(contentView);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    }

   }
```

Minifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Sorry for my english. 
so please me.
THANK YOU.

Comment: I think your logic is good,Have you checked your condition in the debugger `if (status.equals("Paid") && !tr_id.equals("3")` if it works?

Comment: @InnerFire Thanks for replying.

Comment: @InnerFire Thanks for replying. Yes I checked that. but the problem is the broadcast receiver is not run. even this toast it is not showing.     
   Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: does the logcat show any errors?

Comment: @InnerFire No it is not.

Comment: @InnerFire is my way correct ? is there any better way to achieve that ?

Comment: `this.context = context;` would you mind removing this line,see if that works